# Category of a PDE and its properties

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition

Now I am working on numerical method for a PDE. I am considering the following PDE:
$$
u_t+a^2u_{xx}=f\\
u(x,0)=u_0\\
u(x,t)|_\Gamma=u_g
$$
That equation seems very like heat equation which only change a sign of $u_{xx}$ item. I am wondering that is this a kind of parabolic equation? For the definition, the answer seems right. But there no references introduce the properties about it (such as mean value principle and maximum value principle). I just make a program to compute the numerical solution about it and the numerical result shows not very stable. Could any one can introduce some about this equation or tell me which book have the introduction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is instable as is. The equation $u_t  - a^2 u_{xx}=f$ would be stable.

Comment: @daw Yes, I seem it in numerical experiment. But why it is instable? Is there any theoretical results?

Comment: With the transformation $t\to -t$ you see that your problem is a backward heat equation, which is known to be instable (sorry no references at hand).

Comment: The problem is stem form the inverse heat conduction! I am desire some references about it. Thank you for your comments! :)